# Automatically adding a newline to TextBox in WP8.1 XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to build a Windows Phone 8.1 app and there is something that is really bothering me:
![look at this] https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Hhb.png

As you can see the TextBox is not creating and going to a new line when the text reaches its end. What should I do? I tried Googling for it but couldn't really find it (I am sure I used the wrong keywords but I am all new into this).

Anyways, here is the XAML code I am using (with some things I've found on Google but didn't work)

Look at the "contentTextBox":

```
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="WhiteSmoke">

        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TitleRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="titleTextBox" Text="Title"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto">
                <TextBox x:Name="contentTextBox" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" Width="Auto"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turning on TextWrapping helps!

```
<TextBox x:Name="contentTextBox" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         Width="Auto" />
```

It means - when you're out of horizontal space, wrap to another row.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe it was just that. But I still have one question: I am a foreigner (I already translated "Text Wrap" but it didn't help much) and I am still not sure what "TextWrap" really means. On some texts I try TextWrap with different settings (NoWrap, Wrap, etc) and I see no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on TextWrapping, and you also need to remove it from the StackPanel or give it a fixed size.

The StackPanel will allow the TextBox to grow endlessly horizontally, and since you have `Width="Auto"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, the TextBox has no way of knowing when it should stop stretching, and will grow with your Text.

Remove the StackPanel, and keep the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` (Width can be removed, since auto it the default), and the TextBox will take 100% of the width of the screen, and won't resize as you type.

Comment: Did as you told and also set "VerticalAllignment="Stretch" and it is now exactly as I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark either reply as the answer in order to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting

```
<TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

---

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Height="Auto">
            <TextBox x:Name="contentTextBox" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt." HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="Auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

**ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled**" : That means that the ScrollViewer is not giving "Auto" Width to Textbox even if Textbox exceeding its bounded/visible width

**TextWrapping="Wrap"** : If text dosen't fit to its width it comes to next the line.

[image]